# Does VideoCapture() function takes a "list" contain all the videos?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Instead of giving the path, I'm making all the videos I have into a list and trying to pass that list as argument in `VideoCapture()` function of OpenCV. Will that work?

Comment: no....................

Comment: I have a dataset which has 100 action folders and in each action there are 100 videos. So, I need to read all those videos using VideoCapture() function. Could you please help me out?

Comment: you can iterate through every video file in the folder and read them

Comment: the same advice was given on your previous question related to this issue. stop looking for shortcuts. just write the code.